# In XML, how to check if child nodes contain specific values with C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
  <Module Name="CPULIST01" Type="CPULIST" Version="1.1.0.0" Description="UNIT1.2">
    <Connector Name="IF2" NodeNumber="4">
      <Parameter ID="ActivateDevice" Value="1" />
      <Parameter ID="EthInterfaceRedundant" Value="0" />
      <Parameter ID="HostName" Value="if2-br-automation" />
      <Parameter ID="Mode" Value="Manual" />
      <Parameter ID="InternetAddress" Value="192.168.10.49" />
      <Parameter ID="SubnetMask" Value="255.255.255.0" />
      <Parameter ID="ActivateModbus" Value="1" />
      <Parameter ID="NumSlaves" Value="-1" />
      <Parameter ID="NumAllBlocks" Value="-1" />
      <Parameter ID="MemSizeIn" Value="-1" />
      <Parameter ID="MemSizeOut" Value="-1" />
    </Connector>
    <Connector Name="IF3">
      <Parameter ID="Operation" Value="EthOnly" />
      <Parameter ID="Baudrate" Value="100" />
      <Parameter ID="EplEthInterfaceRedundant" Value="0" />
      <Parameter ID="EthernetMode" Value="Manual" />
      <Parameter ID="HostName" Value="if3-eth-br-automation" />
    </Connector>
    <Parameter ID="ConfigurationID" Value="Sx_Startup_NONRED_Unit1" />
    <Parameter ID="Simulation" Value="1" />
    <Parameter ID="VolatileGlobalPvSize" Value="75000" />
    <Parameter ID="TimerDeviceType" Value="EPLX2X" />
    <Parameter ID="TimerDevice" Value="X20IF2181-2.IF1" />
  </Module>
```

Now I want to search if "Simulation" is present in that, how can I do that. 
please suggest.

Comment: Can the element with the ID of `Simulation` be a child of a `Connector` element or is it always going to be a child of the `Module` element?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var doc_xml = new XmlDocument();
//load your xmlfile
doc_xml.Load(@"..\Yourxmlfile.xml");

foreach (XmlNode node in doc_xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
//your code
}
```

Comment: 1. This doesn't actually address the point of the OP - it just shows how to loop tthrough the child nodes of the document element;
2. It only iterates through the immediate children of the document element - if the Parameter element with the ID attribute value of `Simulation` was a child element of a `Connector` element then it would not be one of the `node` values in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using XPath is one way:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var element = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("Module/Parameter[@ID='Simulation']");
if (element != null)
{
    // Simulation is present
}
```

Comment: You welcome, Feel free to upvote + accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = 
                "<Module Name=\"CPULIST01\" Type=\"CPULIST\" Version=\"1.1.0.0\" Description=\"UNIT1.2\">" +
                    "<Connector Name=\"IF2\" NodeNumber=\"4\">" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"ActivateDevice\" Value=\"1\" />" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"EthInterfaceRedundant\" Value=\"0\" />" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"HostName\" Value=\"if2-br-automation\" />" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"Mode\" Value=\"Manual\" />" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"InternetAddress\" Value=\"192.168.10.49\" />" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"SubnetMask\" Value=\"255.255.255.0\" />" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"ActivateModbus\" Value=\"1\" />" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"NumSlaves\" Value=\"-1\" />" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"NumAllBlocks\" Value=\"-1\" />" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"MemSizeIn\" Value=\"-1\" />" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"MemSizeOut\" Value=\"-1\" />" +
                    "</Connector>" +
                    "<Connector Name=\"IF3\">" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"Operation\" Value=\"EthOnly\" />" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"Baudrate\" Value=\"100\" />" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"EplEthInterfaceRedundant\" Value=\"0\" />" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"EthernetMode\" Value=\"Manual\" />" +
                      "<Parameter ID=\"HostName\" Value=\"if3-eth-br-automation\" />" +
                    "</Connector>" +
                    "<Parameter ID=\"ConfigurationID\" Value=\"Sx_Startup_NONRED_Unit1\" />" +
                    "<Parameter ID=\"Simulation\" Value=\"1\" />" +
                    "<Parameter ID=\"VolatileGlobalPvSize\" Value=\"75000\" />" +
                    "<Parameter ID=\"TimerDeviceType\" Value=\"EPLX2X\" />" +
                    "<Parameter ID=\"TimerDevice\" Value=\"X20IF2181-2.IF1\" />" +
                  "</Module>";

            XElement module = XElement.Parse(xml);
            Boolean simulation = module.Descendants("Parameter").Where(x => (x.Attribute("ID").Value == "Simulation") && (x.Attribute("Value").Value == "1")).Any();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've loaded your XML into an `XDocument` you can do it like this with LINQ:

```
var simulationExists = xDocument.Descendants("Parameter").Any(x => (string)x.Attribute("ID") == "Simulation");
```